# canEdit not working in dgrid while loading by default

Tags: dojo, editor, dgrid

I have a tree grid with following ui requirements on edit.

- Cost column for certain rows are editable.
- Editable rows should be available for edit by default always and not
  based on any event.
- Each row has min max range. As and when the user enters a value that
  needs to be validated.

Here is the column structure I have defined for dgrid.

```
var columns = [
        tree({label: "Name", field:"name" }),
        { label : "Description", field:"description" },
        editor({label: "Cost", field: "cost", canEdit : function(rowItem){ return rowItem.isEditable;}}, dijit.form.NumberTextBox),
        {label:"Min - Max Range", field:"minRange", get:getMinMax, id:'minMax'}
];
```

Though the tree and edit is working fine, I have few issues to be resolved.

- When editOn is not provided for editor, the column is made editable
  by default. However, canEdit is getting invoked only when we provide
  spl event in editOn parameter. Is there a way to get canEdit invoked
  even during default load.
- I need to set a range constraint for NumberTextBox dynamically for
  each row. Is there an easy way to set the constraint based on row
  value.

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2):

1. As for canEdit invoked when editOn is false check:
   https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/issues/623
2. As for dynamic set value based on row values you can try :
   on the widget level Extend the Widget : 
    in
   startup after inherited(arguments)

> var _row=this.grid.grid.row(this.domNode.parentNode);
>   this.query={myParam:_row.data.maxRange};
>   
>   Tsemach.